# Ball bouncing off the wall doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, bounce

I am trying to let the ball bounce back when it is about to go off the screen.

I thought it should work with this:

```
 bal.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = -bal.physicsBody?.velocity.dx
```

but it doesn't..

I am getting this error: Could not find an overload for "-" that accepts the suplied arguments.

How to solve this?

Comment: if messing with the velocities is confusing, you can always put an edge loop around the border of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You could do either:

```
if let physicsBody = bal.physicsBody {
    physicsBody.velocity.dx *= -1
}
```

Or

```
bal.physicsBody?.velocity.dx *= -1
```

Or, if you're absolutely certain `bal` has a physics body you could force-unwrap, with either of the following methods:

```
bal.physicsBody!.velocity.dx *= -1
bal.physicsBody!.velocity.dx = -bal.physicsBody!.velocity.dx
```