# Value of optional type CGFloat? not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, sprite-kit

There is a impulse applied to a ball. but this ball keeps moving after that impulse, but I want it to move just a bit. So here is what I am trying:

```
var impulse:CGFloat = 0.22 // bal impulse
```

applying impulse:

```
bal.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(50 * impulse, 50 * impulse))
```

trying to limit the movement:

```
  if bal.physicsBody?.velocity.dx > impulse{
        bal.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = bal.physicsBody?.velocity.dx - impulse
    }
```

But this last piece of code is getting this error:

```
Value of optional type CGFloat? not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or ?
```

How to fix?

Comment: This is essentially the same as your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278390/ball-bouncing-off-the-wall-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 2):

When workking with optionals, you always should unwrap them using `if let`, because if you use the `?` and the value is nil, the code will not execute, and you will not know that there was a nil value.

Use it like this:

```
var impulse:CGFloat = 0.22 // bal impulse

if let body = bal.physicsBody {

     body.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(50 * impulse, 50 * impulse))

     if body.velocity.dx > impulse {
          body.velocity.dx = body.velocity.dx - impulse
     }
}
else
{
   // bal.physicsBody is nil !
}
```

Comment: Whether or not this will do the right thing depends on whether `bal.physicsBody` is a class or a struct.  If it’s a struct, this will take a local copy and change it, having no effect outside the `if`.

Comment: I am asuming it is a Class, or is it not?

Comment: Dunno, code doesn’t state (though I guess you can assume it is if it’s a standard property in sprike kit). But something generally to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Given you’ve asked a similar question recently, you really need to spend some time understanding optionals, as you’ll keep hitting these kind of problems.  You need to get a feel for what optionals are, and what the different techniques are for handling them.  Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623568/3925941) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717211/3925941) to start.

In this particular example, you have an optional `velocity`, because you are accessing it via another optional, `physicsBody`, via “optional chaining” (`?.`).  So to perform an operation like `-` on it, you need to use an optional technique.  This looks like a good case for a `if let` with an extra `where` clause:

```
if let v = bal.physicsBody?.velocity where v.dx > impulse {
    bal.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: v.dx - impulse, dy: v.dy)
}
```

Note, optional chaining can be “assigned through” which is why `bal.physicsBody?.velocity =` works.

Also, there’s no need to use `CGVectorMake`.  Unlike in Objective-C, `CGVector` has an initializer that takes the same parameters (as shown above).